# Animating a pushpin inside Bing maps using Storyboard (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, storyboard, bing-maps, expression-blend

I want to animate an element (pushpin for example) inside the bing maps control using storyboard. is that possible?

I was thinking of adding and removing the pushpin from the MapLayer of the maps control. but it would be easier if I can use the storyboard.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can put your pushpin art as a static resource then your storyboard in as a resource kind of like;

```
<bing:MapLayer>
                    <bing:MapLayer.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="storyBoard">
                            Storyboard contents.....
                        </Storyboard>
                    </bing:MapLayer.Resources>
                    <bing:Pushpin  x:Name="pp" Location="0,0" Template="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplate1}">
                        <bing:Pushpin.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </bing:Pushpin.RenderTransform>
                    </bing:Pushpin>
                </bing:MapLayer>
```

Of course you'll have to fix to meet what your storyboard etc is doing. Hope this helps!